# How to acknowledge the waypoints are done [DJI ROS Python]

Tags: python, ros, dji-sdk

I have DJI M600 Drone and I'm using ROS DJI SDK on Raspberry PI to communicate with it.

I can successfully send waypoint commands and execute them. However, I don't know how to acknowledge that the waypoints are finished. What comes to my mind is that I can check where the drone is in order to compare it with the coordinates I sent. The second solution might be to check how many waypoints are left (haven't tried it yet).

I wonder if there is a topic that I can subscribe to so that I can ask if the waypoints are completed. What is the proper way to do that?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a different SDK so can't help with code example but I think you need to look into:
the wayPointEventCallback and wayPointCallback.